# What can we assume is an invalid email address?

Tags: javascript, regex, email-validation

I am attempting to validate email addresses, however I want the most lenient validation possible as I intend to back this up by sending the user a validation email (I am aware this gets asked a lot but the other questions are focused on being as strict as possible whereas I am attempting to identify the most lenient checks possible).

I still think it's important to have some level of validation to remove things that couldn't possibly be an email address... I don't want `"this is not @n email. fool"` sitting smugly in my database pretending to be an email. Although I am quite happy to have `"this.is.not.an.email@fool.com"`.

Here is my function so far:

```
function validate(email) {
  var atIndex = email.lastIndexOf('@');
  // Make sure email contains an '@' character and that it is neither the first or last character
  if (atIndex > 0 && atIndex < email.length -1) {
    // Everything before the last '@' character
    var local = email.substring(0, atIndex);
    // Everything after the last '@' character
    var domain = email.substring(atIndex + 1, email.length);
    var dotIndex = domain.lastIndexOf('.');

    // Make sure domain contains a '.' character and that it is neither the first or last character
    if (dotIndex > 0 && dotIndex < domain.length - 1) {
      // Array of strings that aren't allowed to appear in a domain
      var domainRestrictions = [
        "..",
        " "
      ];
      var i = domainRestrictions.length;
      while (i-- > -1) {
        if (domain.indexOf(domainRestrictions[i]) > -1) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      // Array of strings that the local portion can neither start or end with
      var localRestrictions = [
        ".",
        " "
      ];
      i = localRestrictions.length;
      while (i-- > -1) {
        var string = localRestrictions[i];
        if (local.indexOf(string) == 0 || local.lastIndexOf(string) == local.length - 1) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      return true;
    }

  }
  return false;
}
```

Currently I disallow the following:

- Anything without an '@' symbol.
- Any domain not containing a '.' or that contains it as the first or last character.
- Any domain containing whitespace or '..' Any local section starting or ending with '.' or whitespace

Everything else is considered valid and passed on.

My question is, are there any valid email addresses this will choke on? Are there any more safe assumptions I can make that an email address can't contain?

Comment: There is no requirement in the RFCs for the domain to contain a '.'.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but personally I don't see a difference between "this is not @n email, dumb dumb" and "not.a.real@email-address.lol". If someone doesn't want to give a real email address, they just make one up. The only good that email validation does is that it might catch unwanted typos the user might make.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples

Comment: @AdrianWragg How would one send an email to such a domain? I am assuming this could only happen on `localhost`?

Comment: @NabilKadimi Too restrictive, the author himself admits it will choke on some valid email addresses. If it can exist I will let them use it.

Comment: @GeorgeReith No; I knew someone (many many years ago) who was admin for a country TLD, whose email address was <initial>@<code> - four letters in total. It only needs an MX record to exist.

Comment: @Juhana If a user is going to give me a fake email I want them to at least put a little effort into it and try to be subtle.

Comment: @AdrianWragg Yikes. I will remove that then and just check whether a `.` is the last character.

Comment: @GeorgeReith My point is more that it's easy to make assumptions based on what you've seen, but there are exceptions everywhere. Does your code cope with Cyrillic or Greek? Unicode?

Comment: @AdrianWragg I was going to punycode the email address before passing it for validation if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are absolutely intent on having a 100% valid email address, for starters I would recommend reading RFC 2822, which can be found at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1. A full implementation of this specification will ensure that all email addresses entered are in a completely valid format. This goes far beyond what all but the most complex regular expressions can achieve - for example, you may find that you need to cope with Cyrillic, Greek or Unicode character sets.

However ...

Implementation of this spec would take a significant amount of time, compared with the amount of time you would save. Even if an email address was still in a valid format there are still gotchas including:

- The domain may not be registered;
- There may be no MX record for the domain;
- There may be no A record for the domain, as a fall-back; or,
- The user may not actually exist.

Quite frankly, rather than spending time ensuring email addresses adhere strictly to the correct format, your time may be better spent ensuring that it is "good enough" and concentrating on other aspects of your verification process.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Regular Expression you'll have a lot less trouble. There are email validation patterns which validate your email address.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourEmailAddress);
if(matcher.matches()){
  //do something
}else {
  //tell the user it didn't match
}
```

Comment: Although I can't read/write regex as far as I am aware these are mostly too restrictive. I also prefer to use snippets of code I myself can maintain if necessary.

Comment: @rouce Top level domains aren't limited to 2-4 characters anymore since ICANN started handing out licenses for generic TLDs.

Comment: @GeorgeReith You should really learn how to read and write regular expressions. It's a very useful skill, even though they are hard to read even for experienced people.

Comment: The problem is that (unless you get to extremely complex levels) every regex has exceptions. test@sample..com is 'valid' under this expression.

Comment: @Philipp Indeed it is on my to-do list, it just gets pushed further back every time I get an idea for a new project. I have a very basic understanding e.g. what `[]`,`+`,`*` mean but that's about it.

Comment: The regular expression I used here, is the one I use in my application. I didn't want to copy paste an expression from any site (I don't know the terms of copyrights and stuff). Thanks for your advice Philipp and Adrian Wragg

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html
Will give you some information about regex in Java

Comment: Since 2010, non-latin characters like Hebrew, Arabic, Chinese, etc are allowed in email addresses. Your regex completely fails on that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check an exhaustive set of rules at -

http://rumkin.com/software/email/rules.php